# output coming wrong in substr() function of program

Tags: c++, string

output coming wrong of code `cout<< substr(temp,1,strlen(word)+1)<<'\n';` The output should come rockstar for the last sentence in array s but coming output rockstar r.

Also the sentence "no one can dare" output is also wrong. It's coming no one **cat**. How **cat** is coming instead of **can**. Please suggest what's causing such kind of problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int par(char s[][80],int,int,char []);
char* substr(char*,int,int);
int main()
{
  char s[][80]={{"this is rockstar"},{"I am rockstar"},{"the best one"},{"no one can dare"},{"rockstar rocks always"}};
  char word[80]={"rockstar"};
  int n1=5;
  int num1=0;
  cout<<par(s,n1,num1,word);
  return 0;
}
int par(char s[][80],int n1,int num1,char word[80])
{
  int k=0;
  int length_word=strlen(word);
  int t=0;
  char beg[80];
  while(t!=strlen(word))
  {
    beg[t]=word[t];
    t++;
  }
  beg[t]=' ' ;
  char end[80];
  char mid[80];
  mid[0]=' ';
  t=0;
  int l=1;
  while(t!=strlen(word))
  {
    mid[l]=word[t];
    l++;
    t++;
  }
  mid[l]=' ';
  t=0;
  l=1;
  end[0]=' ';
  while(t!=strlen(word))
  {
    end[l]=word[t];
    t++;
    l++;
  }

  char temp[80];
  while(k<=n1-1)
  {
    int i=0;
    while(s[k][i]!='\0')
    {
      temp[i]=s[k][i];
      i++;
    }
    if(strcmp(substr(temp,1,strlen(word)),beg)==0)
    {
      num1+=1;
    }
    cout<<substr(temp,1,strlen(word)+1)<<'\n';
    cout<<beg<<" hello"<<'\n';
    int tr;
    for(tr=2;tr<strlen(temp)-(strlen(word)+2);tr++)
    {
      if(strcmp(substr(temp,tr,strlen(word)+2),mid)==0)
      {
        num1+=1;
      }
    }
    if(strcmp(substr(temp,strlen(temp)-strlen(word),strlen(word)+1),end)==0)
    {
      num1+=1;
    }
    k++;


  }
  return num1;
}
char* substr(char *s,int i, int j)
{
  int pos=i-1;
  static char res[80];
  int k=0;
  while(pos<=i+j-2)
  {
    res[k]=s[pos];
    pos++;
    k++;
  }
  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A C-style string must always be zero terminated (`'\0'`). Otherwise it isn't a proper string and not much will work for it. The `substr` function does not seem to add this terminator.

In addition to that, using a static buffer for the return value is *seriously dangerous* as each call to `substr` will destroy the previous return. Using two calls in the same statement or in a multi-threaded app will just not work.

All of this could be solved by using `std::string`, which even has a working `substr` member function.